# pgfplot could not read the plot coordinates

Tags: pgfplots, incompatibility

I have the following latex code that works in one of my machines and it does not work in my other machines (Ubuntu16 and Ubuntu14; may have different versions of latex installed). I suspect there is a pgfplot compatitblity issue. I was wondering if somebody could help me to get this solved in my Ubuntu 14 machine, as the other one is broken:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} \linespread{1.65}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{arrayjob}


\newcommand{\plotprh}[3] {
\subfigure[$\ell=#1$]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=4.2cm, 
        width=5.5cm,
        xlabel={$k'$},
        ylabel={Percent (\%)},
        legend pos=north west,
        legend cell align=left,
        ymin=0,
        ylabel style={at={(0.09,0.5)},font=\small},
        xlabel style={at={(0.5,0.04)},font=\small},
        legend style={at={(0.42,0.06)},anchor=south west, nodes={scale=0.8, transform shape},font=\small,}
    ]
    \addplot[
        color=black,
        mark=square,
        mark size=3,
        ]
        coordinates { % Precision
        #2
        };
    \addplot[
        color=blue,
        mark=diamond,
        mark size=3,
        ]
        coordinates { % Recall
        #3
        };
        \legend{Precision, Recall}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  }


\def\plotData{%
    {3}/{(1,8.627451e+01)(2,6.274510e+01)(3,0.000000e+00)(4,0.000000e+00)}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,0.000000e+00)(4,0.000000e+00)},
    {4}/{(1,9.215686e+01)(2,7.843137e+01)(3,0.000000e+00)(4,0.000000e+00)}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,0.000000e+00)(4,0.000000e+00)},
    {5}/{(1,9.607843e+01)(2,8.627451e+01)(3,5.686275e+01)(4,0.000000e+00)}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,0.000000e+00)},
    {6}/{(1,9.803922e+01)(2,9.019608e+01)(3,7.058824e+01)(4,0.000000e+00)}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,0.000000e+00)},
    {7}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,9.215686e+01)(3,7.843137e+01)(4,5.294118e+01)}/{(1,9.622642e+01)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {8}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,9.607843e+01)(3,8.627451e+01)(4,5.882353e+01)}/{(1,9.107143e+01)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {9}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,9.607843e+01)(3,8.823529e+01)(4,7.058824e+01)}/{(1,8.095238e+01)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {10}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,9.803922e+01)(3,9.019608e+01)(4,7.843137e+01)}/{(1,7.391304e+01)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {11}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,9.803922e+01)(3,9.215686e+01)(4,8.627451e+01)}/{(1,6.144578e+01)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {12}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,9.607843e+01)(4,8.823529e+01)}/{(1,5.543478e+01)(2,9.622642e+01)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {13}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,9.607843e+01)(4,8.823529e+01)}/{(1,4.636364e+01)(2,9.622642e+01)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {14}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,9.607843e+01)(4,9.019608e+01)}/{(1,4.146341e+01)(2,9.272727e+01)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)}}



\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \foreach \el/\recall/\precision in \plotData
    {%
        \plotprh{\el}{\precision}{\recall}%
    }%
    \caption{Results}
    \label{results}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, I could not read the plot coordinates near '(1
,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,0.000000e+00)(4,0.000000e+00) '. Please check
for format mistakes..
See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

Comment: Well, it works fine here at least (`pgfplots` 1.14 in TeX Live 2016).  You can check which version of `pgfplots` you have by adding `\pgfplotsversion` in your document, which prints the version number. (Unrelated: the `subfigure` package is considered deprecated, the newer `subcaption`, or possibly `subfig`, is usually recommended instead.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. So that's probably the problem, as the currently installed version on this system is 1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should uninstall the old TeX Live version and install TeX Live 2016.

But for a quick fix, type the following commands in a terminal:

```
wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots.tds.zip
unzip pgfplots.tds.zip -d ~/texmf
rm pgfplots.tds.zip
```

and your MWE will compile.